# Datasets are not loading

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-cloud-automl

Does anyone have any idea why the Datasets are not loading?

I have some trained datasets, so much so that models are loaded, but not datasets.

Datasets
[image]

Models
[image]

Comment: Hey! I have found this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141889132). It seems that other users have the same issue, so you can comment on the issue tracker and star it in order to follow the process from the team in charge.

Comment: Tks. My datasets are not loading yet. And now the models aren't loading either. I commented there.